# How to implement a property enumerator for a C++ native object in V8?

Tags: c++, v8

I'm writing a Node.js C++ module that communicates with a database which returns BSON objects, and wrap them in a V8 object so they can be accessed from the JavaScript.

For that I create an [ObjectTemplate](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/db/d5f/classv8_1_1_object_template.html), and configure it through [SetHandler](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/db/d5f/classv8_1_1_object_template.html#a0d2b7152eb41450b2bb9c6f6e873d692). My getter and setter work, but the property enumerator does not return anything. Here is the code:

```cpp
void PropertyEnumerator(const PropertyCallbackInfo<Array>& info)
{
    // Enumerator, aka `Object.keys(obj)`
    auto isolate = info.GetIsolate();
    auto data = unrwap_internal_field<BsonObjectData>(info.Holder(), 0);

    Local<Array> array = Array::New(isolate);
    int i = 0;

    bson_iter_t iter;
    bson_iter_init_from_data(&iter, data->document_data, data->document_length);

    while (bson_iter_next(&iter)) {
        const char* key = bson_iter_key(&iter);
        array->Set(i++, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, key, v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked());
    }

    info.GetReturnValue().Set(array);
}
```

- I have checked that the function is actually called
- I have checked that the array is populated with the right values

But in the JavaScript when I do `console.log(Object.keys(obj))` I get an empty array. It's like `info.GetReturnValue().Set(array);` does not do anything. The documentation states that each element of the array must be a `Name`, and `String` inherits from `Name` so I really don't understand.

Thoughts?

Comment: @VTT: `v8::String` inherits from `v8::Name`, so that's fine. -- Another guess: if you have a query callback defined, make sure it returns `ENUMERABLE` for all those properties. If your query callback is nullptr, then the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @jmrk Indeed the problem was that I did not implement the [query](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/d2/dc3/namespacev8.html#a061a7cdf1ffd889df8ec7e871e931a42) function! Returning `PropertyAttribute::None` here made the enumerator work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @jmrk suggested in their comment, the problem was that I didn't implement the [query function](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/d2/dc3/namespacev8.html#a061a7cdf1ffd889df8ec7e871e931a42) for my object template. This made the enumerator work properly:

```cpp
void PropertyQuery(Local<Name> property, const PropertyCallbackInfo<Integer>& info)
{
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(PropertyAttribute::None);
}
```